# How to apply for teaching jobs with no formal teaching experience?

Tags: teaching, career-path

I'd like to make a career change and go into teaching; for financial reasons (I had to care for my elderly parents, etc.) I've been in marketing for 15 years but my true talents lie in writing and teaching.

I've taught several seminars and worked as a college tutor and teaching assistant, run many volunteer writing workshops, and have many publications in literary journals, and a new book coming out this June by a reputable publisher.  I received my MFA in honors and all of my seminar reviews are extremely positive.

I'm just not sure how to apply when every teaching job posting I find lists "at least two years" of college teaching experience as a prerequisite.  At this point I'd even teach a semester free of charge if someone would give me a chance!

Answer (score 2):

You said that your true interest is writing and teaching. If this is the case, then it is justified to join a teaching job.

For this, you already have fair amount of experience such as teaching in seminars and workshops. You might have received some amount of formal appreciation such as a certificate or any written document. This could be added as an experience certificate. You also mentioned that you were TAing for few times. That is a nice experience, which adds to your profile.

When the criterion says "at least 2 years", just mention the above points as follows (or something similar to it):

Teaching experiences:

- Talk on "Title 1" in the International Conference on ABCD
- Taught "Title 2" in the International Workshop on DCBA
- Teaching Assistant (From -- To) at the University of Alphabets